# Use connection string with AzureRM.ServiceBus PowerShell cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, azure, azureservicebus, powershell-cmdlet

To manage Azure Service Bus with AzureRM.ServiceBus PowerShell cmdlets, you get access using Login-AzureRmAccount, e.g.:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroup myRG -NamespaceName myNS
```

Is there a way get access with AzureRM.ServiceBus using a connection string with manage claims? E.g. as when using .NET Framework NamespaceManager:

```
$namespaceManager = [Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager]::CreateFromConnectionString($connectionString)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could include a reference to the .NET assembly for Service Bus and create the NamespaceManager object ($NamespaceManager) from ConnectionString. And then we could use $NamespaceManager later in the script to provision and manage Service Bus entities. For detailed information, please refer to [this documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content-nlnl/blob/master/articles/service-bus/service-bus-powershell-how-to-provision.md).

Comment: Thanks Fred, I've used $NamespaceManager previously. But I want to know if it's possible to use only AzureRM.ServiceBus PowerShell cmdlets which would be more "clean" PowerShell.

Comment: as far as I know, currently it does not enable us to do this if only use [AzureRM.ServiceBus module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.servicebus/v0.0.2/azurerm.servicebus).